# $u^TAv = u^Tv$ implies $A = I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u^TAv = u^Tv$ for a square matrix $A$ of order $n$, does it necessarily imply that $A = I_n$?

Comment: Is that for all $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @Dave Yes, for all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The question should probably be rephrased to something like this: "Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and suppose that $u^T A v = u^T v$ for all $u,v \in \mathbb R^n$. Does it follow that $A = I_n$?"

Comment: @littleO Ok! Sorry for any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is true for every use U and v then can be proceed easily. Just choose U=$e_i$ and v=$e_j$ . Comparing both side s you get required.

Counterexamples can be constructed of this is for just true for some vector 
Hint take u= (0,1) v=(1,0) and A as $2\times 2 $ matrix with $a_{11}$=1 and all other entries are 0.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, for all $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$, we have $$u^TAv=u^Tv\implies u^T(A-I)v=0.$$ So, if we choose $u=e_i$ and $v=e_j$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$, then $u^T(A-I)v$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A-I$, and the above equation says this is zero for all $i,j$. Therefore, $A-I=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If

$u^TAv = u^Tv, \; \forall u, v \in \Bbb R^n, \tag 0$

then yes, $A = I$.  Here's a proof which needs no basis:  given $v \in \Bbb R^n$, set

$u = Av - v; \tag 1$

now note that

$u^TAv = u^Tv \Longleftrightarrow u^T(Av - v) = 0; \tag 2$

thus, with $u$ as in (1) we have

$(Av - v)^T(Av - v) = 0 \Longrightarrow Av - v = 0, \tag 3$

whence

$Av = v, \; \forall v \in \Bbb R^n; \tag 4$

and therefore

$A = I. \tag 5$

Comment: In this case, isn't $u$ dependent on $v$, so the proof does not hold for arbitrary $u, v$?

Comment: @Jan:  Howdy Jan,  We are given that $u^TAv = u^Tv, \; \forall u, v \in \Bbb R^n$ which means we can choose $u$ and $v$ to be whatever we want.  I just chose them conveniently, as was done for basis vectors in the other answers.  Hope this helps.  Welcome to MSE!  Cheers!